# PowerShell script not pulling credentials from encrypted file using Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a batch file as a different user using PowerShell. When I execute the script in PowerShell ISE it works perfectly. When I put it into Task Scheduler to automate it I get the following error:

**ERROR: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Credential'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.**

I am unable to run the batch file as the user I want in Task Scheduler because there is a local policy set that won't let me save the password for that account. That means I can only trigger the task when I am logged into the server. This is my workaround. Task Scheduler is supposed to execute this script and the script runs the batch file under the service account I have stored in the credentials file.

```
$path = "E:\Script"
$error_log = "C:\error.log"
$credential = Import-CliXml -Path "$path\cred.xml"

Try
{
    Start-Process -FilePath "$path\File.bat" -Credential $credential
}
Catch
{
    $_ | Add-Content $error_log
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same user account for task and manual running? Credentials are [secured via DPAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-7.1#:~:text=The%20Export%2DClixml%20cmdlet%20encrypts,or%20by%20a%20different%20user.), so it can't be shared across users or computers.

Comment: The task cannot run under the service account that we need to execute the batch file. I've tried SYSTEM and Administrators. So this is my workaround to run it with the correct user. The problem is there is a local policy that won't let me store passwords in Task Scheduler. Good question.

Comment: Sounds like it might be having issues accessing the file at that path (the xml) so when it's passing through that `$credential` var it's empty since there was nothing written to it. Could see this being an issue if you're in in ISE as administrator.

Comment: I'm logged in as administrator, so Task Scheduler, the script and credentials file are all accessible. I did think about that though. It does make sense, but unfortunately it's not the issue.

Comment: Then ask your network administrator for rights to save the password or for another a solution. Don't try to work around security settings, that road leads to problems sooner or later.